# Seeking clues for packages to generate the example R Shiny outputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am an R Shiny learner, I am just wondering if you have seen this user interface before? If so, do you know:

1. What's the plotting package used here to allow the **hover effect**?
   [image]

2. What's the UI package used here to enable **the extra operations from the menu**?
   [image]

The original Shiny app can be found [here](https://nzpc.shinyapps.io/pbtn23/).
I am aware that extra work is required to get there, but for now I am purely wanted to know where (in terms of the packages) to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left-clicking and looking at page source: view-source:https://nzpc.shinyapps.io/pbtn23/ suggest it is Highcharts, specifically `src="highcharts-9.3.1/highcharts.js"`

See this link for acquisition of the system resource:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/download/

and this link for examples of use within R...

https://rpubs.com/zac-garland/highcharter-chartbook

Answer (score 0):

After googling the targeted area (menu), I have found the source package: It is called **Highcharter**. It is a R wrapper for Highcharts javascript library and its modules.

More info:
https://jkunst.com/highcharter/index.html